# MySQL5.7からMySQL5.7へ、全DBユーザーを移行したい

Tags: mysql

**現在のMySQL5.7で作成したDBユーザーの全てを、新しいMySQL5.7へ移行したいのですがどうすれば良いでしょうか？**
・ユーザ件数が多いので、1件1件指定する以外の方法があれば知りたいです

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・MySQL5.7から新しいMySQL5.7へデータ移行したい
・データはdumpデータ取得しようと思っているが、DBユーザーの移行方法が分からない
※「DBユーザーだけ移行する方法」ではなくて、「DBユーザーを含む全データを移行する方法」があれば、その方法でも良いです

Comment: 同じバージョンであるなら「新しい」という表現は何を指しているのかが分かりづらいです。もし「異なるホスト上への移行」を想定しているなら、そうと分かるようにタイトルや本文も見直してもらった方がよいかと。

Comment: 「ホスト」の概念が良くわかっていないのですが、やりたいことは現在使用しているMySQLを、新しく借りたサーバで同じように動作させることです。それが「異なるホスト上への移行」ですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

userはmysql databaseに保存されているため、それもdumpしてしまえば移行可能なようです。

本家stackoverflowに回答がありました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982299/using-mysqldump-and-database-users
上記URLから引用

mysql tableのみ

> mysqldump ... --routines --databases database_name mysql > backup.sql

すべてのDB

> mysqldump ... --routines --all-databases > backup.sql

Answer (score 1):

全DB、全ユーザーを、別ホストにコピーしたいということであれば、dumpすら使わず、
/var/db/mysql を丸ごとコピーしてはどうでしょうか？
すべてが移行できます。

Comment: 「すべてが移行できます」とありますが、データとユーザ情報以外に何か移行した方がよいものはあるでしょうか？

Comment: DBを、ただ使うだけであれば、それだけでいいと思いますが、丸ごとコピーした場合、それ以外の、DBのログやシーケンスなども移行されます。なくてもいいですが、あって困るものでもないと思います。完全に同じ状態がコピーされると思ってください。

Comment: 「シーケンス」が分からないのですが、採番テーブル？のこと？？ AUTO_INCREMENT に何か影響あるのでしょうか？

Comment: 僕の認識ではmysql でシーケンスと呼ばれるものはないです。（AUTO_INCREMEMTを使う）。また、AUTO_INCREMEMTはdumpに含まれるため、コピーするメリットは含まれないのでは　と思います。